# Sending email id in Google Analytics in android

Tags: android, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am using Google Analytics, I want to send email id  so that I can see browsing flow of of each user, if required. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to trackinformation like that by using [User Id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/user-id)

```
t.set("&uid", user.getId());
```

or sending it as a [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/customdimsmets)

```
// Set the dimension value for index 1.
tracker.setCustomDimension(1, "myValue");
```

> Note: The USER_ID value should be a unique, persistent, and
>   non-personally identifiable string identifier that represents a user
>   or signed-in account across devices.

Make sure you encrypt that email address it is against policy to send identifiable user information to Google Analytics.